# How to replace values present in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table `foo` and I want to replace `null` values present in specific columns with empty string. For  removing null values present in  particular column `x`, I would do like

```
update foo set x = '' where x is null;
```

Is there anyway I would do like,

```
update foo set x,y,z = '' where x,y,z is null;
```

Comment: But why??? Keep the NULLs, and replace empty strings with NULL!

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable answers. Sorry I can't able to upvote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
set 
   x = case when x is null then '' else x,
   y = case when y is null then '' else y,
   z = case when z is null then '' else z
   ...
```

Comment: one more question.. What if I want to remove `null` values globally?

Comment: What do you mean by remove and globally?

Comment: if `null` may or may not present in all the columns. I want to remove all the null values (ie, replace with empty string) irrespective of the col names (ie, global replacement).

Comment: No, you need to state the column names

Comment: Could you explain your query? I think it's like if x is null then replace the null value with empty string else don't do anything or replace it with the same value. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the `case` returns `''` if its `null` else it returns the original value, either of which is then used to update the field.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
   indication = case when  indication is null then '' else indication,
   dos' at line 3`

Comment: This example is missing *END* for closing the *CASE* expression, correct would be:
*x = case when x is null then '' else x end*

Answer (score 1):

This will update all rows, where *any* of columns *x*, *y* or *z* has NULL value and uses [COALESCE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to modify values only in columns where value is NULL:

```
UPDATE
    foo
SET
    x = COALESCE(x, ''),
    y = COALESCE(y, ''),
    z = COALESCE(z, '')
WHERE
    NULL IN (x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is simpler to do this:

```
UPDATE foo SET x='', y='', z='' WHERE x IS NULL AND y IS NULL AND z IS NULL
```

Or this one if you want to edit only the values that are NULL

```
UPDATE foo SET x = IF(x IS NULL, '', x), y = IF(y IS NULL, '', y) ...
```

Comment: it will only replace `NULL` when all 3 x,y,z are NULL

Comment: I think the question is how to replace x and/or y, and/or z.

Comment: What I have to do for all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

UPDATE foo SET x ="", y = "", z = "" WHERE x is NULL and y is NULL and z is NULL